# How to pass data to single file components in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a single file component `header.vue`:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{text}}</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        text: 'Header text',
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

I require it in my code as follows

```
const Header = require('components/header.vue');
```

And call it:

```
const header = new Vue({
  el: '#header',
  data: {
    text: 'New header text',
  },
  render: h => h(Header),
});
```

The component is rendered, but the text says `Header text` instead of `New header text`. Why?

Comment: I suppose you want to dynamically set header title by other components etc? Or what you want to achive ?

Comment: You're creating a new Vue component which renders the Header component as its child. The data from the parent component doesn't affect the data of the child in this way. You can `Vue.extend()` the Header component, then instantiate *that* with an overridden data property.

Comment: @DecadeMoon So you mean `const Header = Vue.extend(require('components/header.vue'));` and then `new Header({ el: ..., data: { ... } });`, right? This works, but it looks a little weird extending the import. Is this really necessary?

Answer (score 11):

You have two separate components here, the Header component and the anonymous component you created (with `new Vue()`). The anonymous component renders the Header component as its child. Both components have separate `data` properties; the parent has `text = 'New header text'` and the child has `text = 'Header text'`.

There are two ways (off the top of my head) that you can achieve this:

1. Extend the Header component and override its `text` data property with the new value:

```js
const Header = require('components/header.vue');
const HeaderComp = Vue.extend(Header);

const header = new HeaderComp({
  el: '#header',
  data: {
    text: 'New header text',
  },
});
```

2. By making `text` a prop instead, you will be able to pass data down to the child from the parent:

**header.vue**

```vue
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['text'],
  };
</script>
```

**usage**

```js
const Header = require('components/header.vue');

// Using render function

const header = new Vue({
  el: '#header',
  render: h => h(Header, {
    props: {
      text: 'New header text',
    },
  }),
});

// Using template

const header = new Vue({
  el: '#header',
  components: {
    Header,
  },
  template: '<header text="New header text"/>',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there can be two ways to solve this:

1. you can pass the header as [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props)

To pass props you have to make following changes in `header.vue`:

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['text'],
  };
</script>
```

And call it:

```
const header = new Vue({
  template: '<header :text="text" />',
  data: {
    text: 'New header text',
  }
});
```

2. You can have header as a [vuex](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPg5eutNDQAhVLQ48KHd-_AKAQFggvMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvuex.vuejs.org%2Fen%2Fintro.html&usg=AFQjCNFMbIAPa_7ajWCvRARuRBgZP50CRg&sig2=Y0m93l91JTqoejC9Ziu9JQ) variable and use it in the `header` component.